# Display flex children to auto resize to fit parent element

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I want to make a listing for images and resize them to fit the window if more are added for it not to expand the parent div.

Can that be done using css `display:flex` option or any other way?

[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sph788fb/)

Css for image holding div and it's children

```
.images{
    background:rgba(14, 11, 10, 0.8);
    display:flex;
    flex:10;
}

.images > img{
     flex:1;
     max-width:100%;
     max-height:100%;
}
```

as you see in the example the image height is not resizing,how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Add each images inside seperate divs, and change style accordingly

```
.images img{
  flex:1;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: As you can see in fiddle the image width adjusts but height does not,how can i fix that

Answer (score 0):

what exactly are you trying to do here? do you want the image to stretch to just the width of the parent div? in which case this is what you should do:

```
.images{
    background:rgba(14, 11, 10, 0.8);
    display:block;
    flex:10;
}
.images img{
    width:100%;
}
```

or do you want the images to stretch to both the width and the height of the parent? in which case you should add an extra height 100% to the image.

Comment: As you can see in fiddle the image width adjusts but height does not,how can i fix that

Comment: shouldn't be a problem to add a fixed height to the picture as this does not affect the responsiveness of your website? so perhaps add a height 200px?

Comment: it would as if there is only 2 images i would preffer having them larger than same size as if there was 5 images

Comment: can you explain again what you're trying to do exactly as your not making alot of sense to me.. no offense :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `flex-direction: column;`

```
.images{
  background:rgba(14, 11, 10, 0.8);
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex:10;
}
```